# Check selector type jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jQuery extension that has an options to pass a target value.

Here is a sample usage of the extension

```
//passed value : #target-element-id
$("<selector>").myFunction({ target: "#target-element-id" });
//target should return an "ID" selector type.
```

Is it possible to validate if passed value is an id, class selector or Is it possible to check what type of selector was used?

For those who are asking why would I need to check the selector type .

It is because I would like to do something like..

```
if (isId) {
    goDance();
}
else if (isClass) {
    goSing();
}
```

Comment: Try to clarify your goal..

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @DiegoPolidoSantana what was the unclear part for you mate? I need to check what type of selector has been pass and that's my goal :)

Comment: Why would you want to check the selector type? What type is it if it is combined such as "#a .b input[type=text]"?

Comment: haha that is why I'm asking haha

Comment: @Vanitas good point! that is why i edited the post awhile ago to check the selector type :) so for this example `#a .b` should return a class I guess, and for the input just return input

Comment: but would you like to know the type from yout target arg>

Comment: or the type from the element you are calling i.e. `$("<selector>")`

Comment: checking the type of the element would be easy by getting the tag type. Is that what you are asking? @DiegoPolidoSantana

Comment: if you would like to know the type from target argument, the SimianAngel's answer is attending you ;)

Comment: maybe you don't need the first selector? i.e. `$.myFunction({ target: "#target-element-id" });`

Comment: How are you targeting unknown elements?

Comment: @Waxi do you mean what if target is undefined? If yes, target was an option .. I have some sort of default . if its undefined it would not proceed anymore on the validation of target

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\s+/` then `.pop()` on `options.target` to retrieve each part of selector string; pass result of `.pop()` to `jQuery()`, call `.prop()` with parameter `"id"` to check strict equality compared to `Array.prototype.slice()` with parameter `1` on result of `.pop()` to check for `id`, else selector is a `className`

```js
function goDance(id) {
  console.log("goDance id:", id)
}

function goSing(c) {
  console.log("goSing class:", c)
}

(function($) {
  $.fn.myFunction = function(options) {
    var type = options.target.split(/\s+|>/).pop();
    if ($(type).prop("id") === type.slice(1)) {
      goDance(type);
    } else {
      goSing(type);
    }
  }
}(jQuery));

$("#div").myFunction({target:"#targetId>.targetClass1"}); // `goSing`
$("#div").myFunction({target:"body #targetId"}); // `goDance`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="div"></div>
<div class="targetClass">target class</div>
<div id="targetId">target id<span class="targetClass1">target class 1</span></div>
```

Comment: would this work if I put a selector like `#targetId>.targetClass1` ?

Comment: @JF-Mechs Presently, no. Though you could add `>` to `RegExp` at `.split()`; e.g., `.split(/\s+|>/)`

Answer (score 0):

For a simple determination of id or class, you could check the first character of the target string:

```
var selectorType;
var targetFirstCharacter = options.target.charAt(0);

switch (targetFirstCharacter) {
    case "#":
        selectorType = "id";
        break;
    case ".":
        selectorType = "class";
        break;
    case "[":
        selectorType = "attribute";
        break;
    default:
        if (targetFirstCharacter.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
            selectorType = "tag";
        }
}
```

Comment: I've already thought of this , checking the first character but as per Vanitas and what I have just realized how about for the selectors like `#a .b` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<input id="file" type='file' onchange="" />
<div class="oi"></div>
<p>para</p>
<div id="content" class="hello">
    <p class="st"></p>
</div>
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        function detect(selector){
            console.log("-------------");
            console.log("selector",selector);
            var type = "undefined";
            var allParts = [];
            var parts = selector.split(" ");
            var lastPart = parts[parts.length-1];
            var parray = lastPart.split(/(#|\.)/);
            var strToTest = parray[parray.length-1];
            console.log("strToTest",strToTest);
            //try to find something
            if($(selector).size() > 0){
                //is class
                if($(selector).hasClass(strToTest)){
                    type = "class selector";
                }
                else if($(selector).attr("id") == strToTest){
                    type = "id selector";
                }else{
                    if($(selector).is(strToTest)){
                        type = "element selector";
                    }else{
                        //undefined
                    }
                }
            }
            //console.log(type);
            return type;
        }
        console.log(detect(".oi"));
        console.log(detect("#file"));
        console.log(detect("p"));
        console.log(detect("canvas#canvas"));
        console.log(detect("div#content.hello"));
        console.log(detect("div#content .st"));
        console.log(detect("div#content p.st"));

    });
</script>
```